# vb.net threading sub slower than call sub

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, performance

I know this Question was already posted, but it was never really answered, or I did not understand the answer :)

My Problem is that when I call this Sub within the Thread, it takes about 4 sec to execute the code, but if I make a simple Call Sub (Like commented in Code) it takes about 450 ms.

I have a simple program with 2 Subs:

1. To report Progress on Main Form
2. To do some "For" Looping

   ```
   Imports System.Data.SqlClient

   Public Class Form1
   Public Delegate Sub ProzentDelegate(ByVal Prozent As Double)

   Dim G_I_Temp As Integer = 0
   Dim G_S_Prüfziffer As String
   Dim G_S_Präfix As String
   Dim G_I_Zähler As Integer
   Dim G_I_Stellen As Integer
   Dim G_D_Step As Integer = 1
   Dim G_I_Position As Integer
   Dim DT_G_Prüftabelle As DataTable
   Dim DR_G_Prüftabelle As DataRow
   Dim thisLock As New Object
   Dim conn As String = "Data Source=SR-SQLWVS;Initial Catalog=Barcode;Integrated Security=True"
   Dim sourceconn As New SqlConnection(conn)
   Dim adap As SqlDataAdapter
   Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP(10) * FROM dbo.Prüf_Tabelle", sourceconn)

   Dim Thrd_preview As Threading.Thread


   Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       sourceconn.Open()

       cmd.Connection = sourceconn
   End Sub

   Public Sub ReportProgress(ByVal Prozent As Double)
       ProgressBar1.Value = Prozent
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       If RB_Thread.Checked Then

           If Thrd_preview IsNot Nothing Then Thrd_preview = Nothing
           Thrd_preview = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf DoSomeWork)
           Thrd_preview.IsBackground = True
           Thrd_preview.Start()

       Else
           DoSomeWork()
       End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub DoSomeWork()


       Dim ds As New DataSet
       DT_G_Prüftabelle = ds.Tables.Add("Prüf_Tabelle")

       Dim L_I_Counter, L_I_Counter2 As Integer
       Dim L_I_Ende As Integer
       Dim L_I_Step As Integer
       Dim L_I_Nutzen As Integer = 1
       L_I_Step = 1
       L_I_Ende = Val(TB_Auftrag_neu_Anzahl.Text)
       G_I_Stellen = 8
       G_S_Prüfziffer = "1"
       G_S_Präfix = "00"
       If TB_Info_Increment.Text = "" Then TB_Info_Increment.Text = 1




   adap = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP(10) * FROM dbo.Prüf_Tabelle", sourceconn)

       adap.FillSchema(DT_G_Prüftabelle, SchemaType.Mapped)

       DT_G_Prüftabelle.Rows.Clear()

       Dim pre As Date = Now

       For L_I_Counter = 1 To (L_I_Ende * L_I_Step) Step L_I_Step
           For L_I_Counter2 = 1 To L_I_Nutzen
               DR_G_Prüftabelle = DT_G_Prüftabelle.NewRow
               DR_G_Prüftabelle.Item("Auftrag_Lfd_nr") = TB_KeyLot.Text
               DR_G_Prüftabelle.Item("Position") = G_I_Position
               G_I_Position += G_D_Step
               DR_G_Prüftabelle.Item("Barcode_soll") = F_Berechnung((Trim(Str(Val(TB_Auftrag_neu_Von.Text) + L_I_Counter - 1))).PadLeft(G_I_Stellen, "0"))
               DT_G_Prüftabelle.Rows.Add(DR_G_Prüftabelle)

           If ProgressBar1.InvokeRequired Then
               ProgressBar1.BeginInvoke(New ProzentDelegate(AddressOf ReportProgress), (L_I_Counter * 100) / (L_I_Ende * L_I_Step))
           Else
               ReportProgress((L_I_Counter * 100) / (L_I_Ende * L_I_Step))
           End If

           Next



       Next


       MsgBox(Now.Subtract(pre).TotalMilliseconds.ToString & " ms.")


   End Sub


   Function F_Berechnung(ByVal L_Nummer As String) As String
       Dim L_B_Gerade As Boolean = False
       Dim L_I_Prüfziffer As Integer
       Dim L_I_Stellen As Integer
       Me.G_I_Temp = 0

   Select Case G_S_Prüfziffer
       Case "0"
           F_Berechnung = L_Nummer
       Case "1"
           F_Berechnung = G_S_Präfix & Trim(L_Nummer)
       Case "2"
           F_Berechnung = G_S_Präfix & Trim(L_Nummer)
       Case "3"
           F_Berechnung = L_Nummer
           '
       Case "5"    '-----Mod 10 gewichtung 31...-----
           L_Nummer = G_S_Präfix & Trim(L_Nummer)
           L_I_Stellen = Len(L_Nummer)
           For Me.G_I_Zähler = L_I_Stellen To 1 Step -1
               Me.G_I_Temp += Val(Mid(L_Nummer, Me.G_I_Zähler, 1)) * IIf(L_B_Gerade, 1, 3)
               L_B_Gerade = Not L_B_Gerade
           Next
           L_I_Prüfziffer = IIf(10 - Me.G_I_Temp Mod 10 = 10, 0, 10 - Me.G_I_Temp Mod 10)
           F_Berechnung = Trim(L_Nummer) & Trim(Str(L_I_Prüfziffer))
           '
       Case "6"    '-----Mod 10 gewichtung 13...-----
           L_Nummer = G_S_Präfix & Trim(L_Nummer)
           L_I_Stellen = Len(L_Nummer)
           For Me.G_I_Zähler = L_I_Stellen To 1 Step -1
               Me.G_I_Temp += Val(Mid(L_Nummer, Me.G_I_Zähler, 1)) * IIf(L_B_Gerade, 3, 1)
               L_B_Gerade = Not L_B_Gerade
           Next
           L_I_Prüfziffer = IIf(10 - Me.G_I_Temp Mod 10 = 10, 0, 10 - Me.G_I_Temp Mod 10)
           F_Berechnung = Trim(L_Nummer) & Trim(Str(L_I_Prüfziffer))
           '


       Case Else
           F_Berechnung = L_Nummer

   End Select

   End Function
   ```

I have tried to take out Progress Reporting but the Result is the same.

I hope you have some suggestions or solutions for me. I would be very thankful.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is not a code that we can test

Comment: A common technique is to only update the progress on every nth iteration, rather than updating it every time.  For instance, to update it after every 100th iteration you could say something like `If L_I_Counter Mod 100 = 0 Then ReportProgress(Progr)`

Comment: I have updated the original code so you can reproduce the problem and test it. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it seems like there's nothing that should take time in the loop, why even change the progress bar? Looks like the only thing that could be slow is the query. An other option would be to update the progress bar less often because clearly, the differences between the two is the Invoke calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to report that I found a solution.

The main problem was this line of code in:

```
DR_G_Prüftabelle.Item("Auftrag_Lfd_nr") = TB_KeyLot.Text
```

So if I start this Sub from another Thread rather than from a Main Thread, for every single loop it has to go to main thread and to take Paramater from TextBox and to go back in Thread to Loop further.

I took that out, declared a variable at the begining and assigned this TextBox value to it and it works like charm.

Also I took a suggestion from dbasnett to Invoke Reporting every time without If-Else and also the suggestion from Steven Doggart to Report every 100 Loops.

You guys helped a lot. Thanks for that!!

Answer (score 1):

Give these changes a try

Change this

```
        If ProgressBar1.InvokeRequired Then
            ProgressBar1.Invoke(New ProzentDelegate(AddressOf ReportProgress), Progr)
        Else
            ReportProgress(Progr)
        End If
```

to

```
            ReportProgress(Progr)
```

And change method ReportProgress to

```
Public Sub ReportProgress(ByVal Prozent As Double)
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                       ProgressBar1.Value = Prozent
                   End Sub)
End Sub
```

See if that makes a difference. The check for InvokeRequired is not needed, the answer is always yes.

Comment: _"the answer is always yes"_ - If called solely by a background thread then I agree with you, however since this is in a separate method one might decide use it on the UI thread as well, in which case invoking will cause extra, unnecessary overhead.

Comment: When there is only one line you can write it shorter as :   Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() ProgressBar1.Value = Prozent)